# Storing a WebSocket connection in an object (ws library)

Tags: node.js, oop, websocket

I've been messing around trying to create a backend for an IOS game using WebSockets (with the ws library for node.js). So I've figured out the basics of the ws library (ws.on listeners, ws.send etc. and I'm able to send a basic echo message using echo). However, I tried to store each ws connection in a "Player" object, so it would be easily accessible by having a function in the websocket server class like:

```
sendMyMessage(ws) {
ws.send("Message")
}
```

and calling:

```
WebSocketServerInstance.sendMyMessage(PlayerInstance.ws)
```

Maybe not with that exact syntax, but you get the idea... Since a ws connection is an object itself (so, presumably a reference type, not a value type), this should work so long as I call sendMyMessage() on the same WebSocketServer instance that received the connection, right? Or am I missing something critical / not approaching this in the right way?

When I do something like this, my IOS debugger doesn't receive anything (however if I console.log the ws object in the sendMyMessage() function in Node, it does in fact output what I am assuming is the correct ws object), but it works with all the other more basic functions I described above, like sending a message back using a "ws.on('message, ...) listener.

Comment: You're going to get a quicker answer if you state the question clearly. Like: "How do I ______?".